# Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. If the Lebesgue measure $\mu (K)$ of all compact subsets $K\subseteq A$ is zero, then $\mu (A)=0.$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm struggling with one part of a proof from W. Rudin's 'Real and Complex Analysis'. It asserts that, if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R},$ then:

$$\mu (K)=0 \text{ for all compact } K\subseteq A \Longrightarrow \mu(A)=0.$$

What am I missing? What makes this true without need for explanation?

Comment: maybe Rudin already explained that the Lebesgue measure is a regular measure

Comment: This may well be the case, in which case I have some more reading to do.

Comment: Indeed. You are looking for something like Theorem 2.14 in combination with Definition 2.15 and Theorem 2.20. Key term is inner regular.

Comment: Which proof are you referring to?

Comment: @Furrer Appreciated.

Comment: @Coriolanus Theorem 2.22, penultimate paragraph.

Comment: @mrbronstedlowry When you have pieced everything together, feel free to submit and accept your own answer.

Comment: I actually wrote a proof of this for a wiki article I had to write in my Real Analysis class. Here's a [link to it](http://34.106.105.83/wiki/Approximation_by_Open/Compact_Sets) in case you're interested. It is Folland theorem 1.18 if you're looking for a textbook reference.

Comment: @DanielApsley What a coincidence! Thanks, it looks really useful, will take a look.